# LazyColumn not loading in fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

When a fragment is launched, LazyColumn does not display information, and when switching to another fragment, it first adds elements to the screen (can be duplicated), then switches.

```
Column () {
            LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                items(viewModel.chats) { item ->
                    Text(item.name)
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: We need more code and more clarity.

Comment: Don't use fragments...

Comment: will be great if a video and more elaborated code is given for understanding